# How to resetup Brother MFC-J480DW for scanning after it changed its IP?

Tags: scanner, brother

Every time I restart my router or for other reasons my printer changes its IP and I can't print or scan anymore. Setting up the printer is straightforward but the scanner not so much.

How can I reregister the scanner under the correct IP?

The printer/scanner is a Brother MFC-J480DW.

Answer (score 0):

[Official Linux Drivers for Brother MFC-J480DW](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcj480dw_us_eu_as&os=128#SelectLanguageType-566_0_1)

1) Look up on network and set up using the regular printers tool. Copy its IP.

2) Identify possibly already registered scanner:

```
$ brsaneconfig4 -q | tail
414 "MFC-7460DN"
415 "MFC-7360"
416 "MFC-7860DN"
417 "DCP-7065DN"
418 "DCP-7060D"
419 "DCP-7055"

Devices on network
  0 MFC-J480DW          "MFC-J480DW"        I:192.168.1.2
```

3) Remove scanner:

```
brsaneconfig4 -r MFC-J480DW
```

4) Reregister scanner with correct IP:

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=MFC-J480DW model=MFC-J480DW ip=192.168.1.3
```

Comment: what is brsaneconfig4?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=brsane , and Mint?   The answer should be Ubuntu to be on-topic - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: it's a program shipped with linux drivers and there is nothing Mint specific.